# Asyncio print status of coroutines progress

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, coroutine

I have a bunch of coroutines that doing some work

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def do_work():
    global COUNTER
    result = ...
    if result.status == 'OK':
        COUNTER += 1
```

and another one

```
COUNTER = 0
@asyncio.coroutine
def display_status():
    while True:
        print(COUNTER)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
```

which have to display how many coroutines have finished their work. How to properly implement this task? Following solution doesn't work

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def spawn_jobs():
    coros = []
    for i in range(10):
        coros.append(asyncio.Task(do_work()))
    yield from asyncio.gather(*coros)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(display_status())
    loop.run_until_complete(spawn_jobs())
    loop.close()
```

I expect that counter will be printed to the console every second no matter what do_work() coroutines do. But I have just two outputs: 0 and after a few seconds repeating 10.

Comment: One of possible options is to add print(COUNTER) into `do_work()` function, but I want printing `COUNTER` every second and not after finishing piece of work

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very specific. What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: don't put additional info in the comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: unrelated: use `asyncio.create_task()` instead of `asyncio.Task()`. Moreover, you could don't need neither  in this case: `yield from asyncio.wait([do_work() for _ in range(10)])` works as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I have just two outputs: 0 and after a few seconds repeating 10.

I can't reproduce it. If I use:

```
import asyncio
import random

@asyncio.coroutine
def do_work():
    global COUNTER
    yield from asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    COUNTER += 1
```

I get the output like this:

```
0
0
4
6
8
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<display_status() running at most_wanted.py:16> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()] created at ../Lib/asyncio/tasks.py:490> created at most_wanted.py:27>
```

The infinite loop in `display_status()` causes the warning at the end. To avoid the warning; exit the loop when all tasks in the batch are done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import random
from contextlib import closing
from itertools import cycle

class Batch:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.total = n
        self.done = 0

    async def run(self):
        await asyncio.wait([batch.do_work() for _ in range(batch.total)])

    def running(self):
        return self.done < self.total

    async def do_work(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5)) # do some work here
        self.done += 1

    async def display_status(self):
        while self.running():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print('\rdone:', self.done)

    async def display_spinner(self, char=cycle('/|\-')):
        while self.running():
            print('\r' + next(char), flush=True, end='')
            await asyncio.sleep(.3)

with closing(asyncio.get_event_loop()) as loop:
    batch = Batch(10)
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([
        batch.run(), batch.display_status(), batch.display_spinner()]))
```

#### Output

```
done: 0
done: 2
done: 3
done: 4
done: 10
```

Comment: The problem was in using synchronous code inside `do_work()`. I use synchronous calls `r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')` so them block my displaying status coroutine. Seems like I need to switch to the aiohttp for making requests.

Comment: When I insert `r = yield from aiohttp.request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', data=data)` instead of **sleep()** I can just do less than 512 batch jobs. Otherwise I have an error: `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`. Is that _aiohttp_ restriction or something else?

Comment: @MostWanted: you should ask a separate question. [Provide a *minimal* but complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), enable [`asyncio` debug mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-debug-mode), include the full traceback. My guess, you need something like `result = yield from r.json()` to read the response.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `threading` module

```
SHOW_STATUS = True
def display_status_sync():
    while SHOW_STATUS:
        print(S_REQ)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_thread = threading.Thread(target=display_status_sync)
    new_thread.start()
    loop.run_until_complete(spawn_jobs())
    SHOW_STATS = False
    new_thread.join()
    loop.close()
```

But I want to achieve similar functionality using asyncio coroutines. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Also I can use `loop.run_in_executor(None, display_status_sync)` instead of creating threads. That will produce the same effect.